# I can init and fetch file with git-svn, but can't clone

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

I read the manual and it said `clone` is `Runs init and fetch`.

But I tried this:

```
git svn clone -T http://svn.felspar.com/public/m-intercept/trunk/
```

then got:

> fileparse(): need a valid pathname at /usr/lib/git-core/git-svn line 405

And not any file was downloaded.

But when I used:

```
git svn init http://svn.felspar.com/public/m-intercept/trunk/
git svn fetch
```

All right. It works perfectly. I use the exact same URL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The -T parameter expects the name of the trunk dir.

Normal usage would be

```
git svn clone -T trunk -t tags -b branches http://svn.felspar.com/public/m-intercept
```

to tell git where to look for trunk, tags and branches and map them to git tags and branches.

Comment: Sure, just leave out the -t and -b parts.